# Menu Item Location

Tags: menus, notifications

I found code to show a notification bar on menu and customize it a little. It is working and shown on main menu (primary menu) and footer menu (secondary menu) but I want to show it only main menu. How to do that? Here's what I have:

```
function my_counter_nav_menu( $menu ) {  
    $notif_url   = bp_core_get_user_domain( bp_loggedin_user_id() ) . 'notifications/';
    $friends_url = bp_core_get_user_domain( bp_loggedin_user_id() ) . 'friends/'; 
    $msg_url     = bp_core_get_user_domain( bp_loggedin_user_id() ) . 'messages/';    

    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        return $menu;
    } else {
        $notif = '<li><a href=" ' . $notif_url . ' "> <i class="fa fa-bell-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Notifications [' . bp_notifications_get_unread_notification_count( bp_loggedin_user_id() ) . ']</a></li>';
    }

    $menu = $menu . $notif;

    return $menu;
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'my_counter_nav_menu' );
```

Answer (score 2):

The [`wp_nav_menu_items`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_nav_menu_items/) filter has a secondary parameter that it passes: `$args`. What we need to do is set up our filter to accept second args by passing a priority `10` and the number of args `2`:

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'my_counter_nav_menu', 10, 2 );
```

Now that we're passing args - if we peek into what it holds we see the following object:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [menu] => Menu Name
    [container] => nav
    [container_class] => 
    [container_id] => mainNav
    [menu_class] => menu
    [menu_id] => 
    [echo] => 1
    [fallback_cb] => wp_page_menu
    [before] => 
    [after] => 
    [link_before] => 
    [link_after] => 
    [items_wrap] => <ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>
    [depth] => 0
    [walker] => 
    [theme_location] => 
)
```

So if we wanted to in your function we can test against either `$args->menu` or `$args->theme_location`:

```
if( 'Menu Name' === $args->menu ) {
    /* .. Run Code Here .. */
}
```

Or against the location:

```
if( 'primary-menu' === $args->theme_location ) {
    /* .. Run Code Here .. */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi thx for your answering ,but i confused shall I define one of stdclass objects like  [menu] => Menu Name or [theme_location] => 
İf so,Is it neccessary to change
Menu Name which on you typed
[menu] => Menu Name
Could u send me hole ordered codes,pls?